# want jQuery on my Driod

Tags: jquery, android

Is any Android browser able to process jQuery scripts?

which will be the 1st when?

Comment: Well, since jQuery is just javascript, any browser that can run javascript, can run jQuery.

Comment: umm...yeah...that'd be my doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine now.